# Firebase emulator always returns Error: 2 UNKNOWN after trying out the firestore background trigger functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

[image]
** This is that my firestore (emulator) looks like**

I am trying to practice learning about cloud functions with firebase emulator however, I am running into this probably more often than I expected. I hope it is my end's problem.

I am trying to write a function where when the user made the https request to create an order, the background trigger function will return out the total (quantity * price) to the user. The later part is still WIP at the moment; I am currently just trying to understand and learn more about cloud functions.

This is the https request code I have to add the item, price, and quantity to my firestore. It works well and as intended.

```
exports.addCurrentOrder = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
 const useruid = req.query.uid;
 const itemName = req.query.itemName;
 const itemPrice = req.query.itemPrice;
 const itemQuantity = req.query.itemQuantity;
 console.log('This is in useruid: ', useruid);

 const data = { [useruid] : {
   'Item Name': itemName,
   'Item Price': itemPrice,
   'Item Quantity': itemQuantity,
 }};

 const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection('Current Orders').add(data);
 res.json({result: data});
});
```

This is the part that's giving me all sorts of errors:

```
exports.getTotal = functions.firestore.document('Current Orders/{documentId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
  const data = snap.data();
  for(const i in data){
    console.log('This is in i: ', i);
  }
  return snap.ref.set({'testing': 'testing'}, {merge: true});
});
```

Whenever I have this, the console will always give me:

```
functions: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: 
at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/Users/user/firecast/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:30:26)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/user/firecast/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:175:52)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/user/firecast/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:341:141)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/user/firecast/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:304:181)
at Http2CallStream.outputStatus (/Users/user/firecast/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:116:74)
at Http2CallStream.maybeOutputStatus (/Users/user/firecast/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:155:22)
at Http2CallStream.endCall (/Users/user/firecast/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:141:18)
at Http2CallStream.handleTrailers (/Users/user/firecast/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:273:14)
at ClientHttp2Stream.<anonymous> (/Users/user/firecast/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:322:26)
at ClientHttp2Stream.emit (events.js:210:5)
Caused by: Error
at WriteBatch.commit (/Users/user/firecast/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:415:23)
at DocumentReference.create (/Users/user/firecast/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:283:14)
at CollectionReference.add (/Users/user/firecast/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:2011:28)
**at /Users/user/firecast/functions/index.js:43:76** 
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:593:20
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:568:19
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:8:71
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at __awaiter (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:4:12)
⚠  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
```

Even if I comment out the function that I think is giving me the error, I will still run into this problem (and when I run the sample function found on the official cloud function guide too!)

I know there is definitely something that I am doing horribly wrong on the background trigger (and would love to have someone be kind enough to show me how to write such function/get me startted)

What am I doing wrong here? Or is this some sort of the emulator bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it. Although I think there is better solution possible.

On completely new system+firebase I have used [this firebase emulators tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_and_prototype?database=Firestore#prototype_interactively) to create first `onCreate` trigger called `makeUppercase` and it worked. Than I added your `getTotal` and it was not working and as well it spoiled the `makeUppercase` trigger as well!

I started to test some changes. Tried many times and, finally, I have removed "space" character from collection name like this:

```
exports.getTotal = functions.firestore.document('CurrentOrders/{documentId}')...etc.
```

Both triggers started working as well (used fresh VM with Windows+node12). It's possible that it will be working on real Firestore instance. So it seems the "space" in collection name is generating some errors in whole `index.js`.

Comment: Thanks. It did seemed like it's a spacing problem, but I changed the 'add(data)' to collection('CurrentOrders) without the space or else the function getTotal wouldnt run. And it worked! Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred for me on the Emulator because I had a faulty (unrelated) function trigger path in my project (I'd forgotten to add a trailing slash between a collection and a document part of the path).

One I fixed the function path, the error was resolved.

Comment: Similar thing with me but it was I accidentally had ${docId} instead of just {docId}.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur if the LOCATION has not been defined for your emulated function, you can see this in your terminal eg:

```
functions[${LOCATION-fn]: firestore function initialized.
```

Ensure you have a suitable location defined in your Environmental variables.